# "The system is running in low-graphic mode" issue on ubuntu 16.04 after booting

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gdm

This morning I booted my Ubuntu partition through Grub as normal, but instead of going to the log in screen, it showed the black page with error message "The system is running in low-graphic mode". I haven't installed anything yesterday so this is unexpected.
I have tried various things to solve it following what people suggested but nothing seemed to work:

some info on the system:

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

```
eric@eric-ThinkPad-P50s:~$ sudo lshw -C display
[sudo] password for eric: 
*-display UNCLAIMED     
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 07
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f0000000-f0ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff 
ioport:e000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
*-display UNCLAIMED
   description: 3D controller
   product: GM108GLM [Quadro K620M / Quadro M500M]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
   version: a2
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f1000000-f1ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff 
memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:d000(size=128)
```

To get to a terminal, I logged into the safemode, and failsafeX, but using CTRL+ALT+F1 did not bring me to the terminal. After I click on failsafeX, I got brought back to the menu where I could choose, "resume", which I did, and I ended up logging as a guest.

Then from the terminal, I tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

rebooted, issue still there

Then I tried

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current - More stable/tested version 
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates - More up-to-date version
```

same.

I also tried:

```
sudo apt-get -d install --reinstall gdm
sudo apt-get remove --purge gdm
sudo apt-get install gdm
sudo reboot
```

Same issue still there.

Help would be much appreciated because I am out of options

Cheers

E.

Answer (score 0):

I apparently solved it by installing:
https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.2

it requires to install gdebi
https://01.org/linuxgraphics/documentation/running-update-tool-using-gdebi

after update and reboot, the error disappeared.

E.